# inject additional blocks into twig template

Tags: twig

I have my base template

```
<html>
<head>
.....
</head>

<body>
{% block body_content %}{% endblock %}

{% block debug_output %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

and my page template

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block body_content %}
.....
{% endblock %}
```

Now after I have loaded the template I want to add to something to the debug_output block.

```
{% block debug_output %}
.....
{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Not using any framework just twig as my template engine.

---

*This is the flow of calling the template I currently have*

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(); 
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader); 
$template = twig->loadTemplate($page_template); 
/* Add additional template to insert into debug_output block here */ 
$template->render($vars);
```

Comment: After 'loaded', do you mean you need to add content with Ajax ?

Comment: This is the flow of calling the template I currently have

`$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem();  
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);  
$template = twig->loadTemplate($template);  
/* Add additional template to insert into debug_output block here */  
$template->render($vars);`

Comment: Perhaps you can do something with this [plugin](https://github.com/rybakit/twig-extensions-deferred). It delays the render of a certain `block` you mark with `defered`

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. I don't want to delay the render of the block. I want to include another template which has the content for the debug_output block after I have loaded the page template.

Comment: Includes can't change the content of a `block`, I also struggled and still stuggle with this as I have a block `javascript` in my base template which I can't  alter when being in an include. I gave up on doing that after serveral hours of research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up and the solution I came up with was to not use a block but an object variable and loop over the properties to add the debug info I wanted. This object was merged with $vars and passed in to the `$template->render($vars)` line.